# python ftplib encoding

Tags: python, python-3.x, кодировка, ftp

Не получается скопировать файл с FTP.

Рабочий код, пытаюсь сделать универсальным для разных ftp серверов:

```
import ftplib

kontr = parse_config(chain)

ftp = ftplib.FTP(kontr['ftp']['server']) 
ftp.login(kontr['ftp']['user'], kontr['ftp']['pwd'])
ftp.cwd(kontr['ftp']['path']['order'])
ftp.encoding = kontr['ftp']['encoding'] #windows-1251
ftp_files = ftp.nlst() #Без ftp.encoding будет падать на чтении

... # Сравнение локальной папки и ftp

if len(file_new) > 0:
    for file in file_new:
        with open(kontr['file']['order_in'] + file, 'wb') as local_file: # Создаем локальный файл в режиме двоичной записи
            ftp.retrbinary('retr ' + file, local_file.write)  # Открываем файл на сервере и делаем его копию в локальный файл
    ftp.close()
    read_file(chain, file_new) #Обработка скачанного файла
else:
    ftp.close()
```

`ftp.file.encoding` = utf-8 и доступно только для чтения

Падает на `ftp.retrbinary('retr ' + file, local_file.write)`
**Ошибка: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 44: invalid start byte**

Windows 10
Python 3.10.4

**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\Desktop\Test\Test.py", line 63, in check_new_file
    ftp.retrbinary('retr ' + file, local_file.write)
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 436, in retrbinary
    with self.transfercmd(cmd, rest) as conn:
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 393, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 359, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 281, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 244, in getresp
    resp = self.getmultiline()
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 230, in getmultiline
    line = self.getline()
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ftplib.py", line 212, in getline
    line = self.file.readline(self.maxline + 1)
  File "C:\Users\my_acc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc0 in position 44: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Имя файла содержит кириллицу? Добавьте полный трэйсбэк ошибки

Comment: @insolor трэйсбэк - добавил. Пример имени - `АО Пупкин_2118031_210506_183127130_0908943211.ORD` - внутри xml, просто люди разделяют внутри одной папки заказы, накладные, прайсы по своему расширению файла

Comment: открой и посмотри что там за символ на позиции 44

Comment: @Эникейщик Первая строка `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" standalone="yes" ?>`, как понимаю пробел, но он уже был до 44 и не падал на нём

Comment: а что такое file_new? Там же цикл, может быть, ошибка не на первой итерации возникает, а на какой-то другой строчке?

Comment: Пробуйте кодировку (cp1251, как указано у вас в xml файле) указывать сразу при создании объекта FTP. При создании объекта без указания кодировки сразу создается соединение с кодировкой по умолчанию (utf-8): [`__init__`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdb61.png), [`connect`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h58hf.png), [исходник ftplib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/ftplib.py#L109)

Comment: @Эникейщик массив имен файлов, которые есть на ftp, но нет локально

Comment: @insolor пробовал. Это кодировка ftp. А если провалиться в ftp.file.encoding, то там utf-8 и доступен только для чтения параметр

Comment: @MaxDown, file создается в методе connect, кодировка берется из self.encoding. Сonnect вызывается из `__init__`, и если при создании объекта не указана кодировка, то будет использоваться utf-8. У вас в примере вы сначала создаете объект FTP без указания кодировки, потом прописываете кодировку, которая уже ни на что не повлияет, потому что файловый объект сокета уже создан с кодировкой по умолчанию. Пробуйте еще раз с `ftp = ftplib.FTP(kontr['ftp']['server'], encoding="cp1251")`

Comment: в utf8 нет символов, начинающихся на 0xC0, а в win1251 это русская "А", что очень похоже на содержание ваших файлов. Так что действительно, нужно использовать не юникод

Comment: @insolor Помогло `ftp = ftplib.FTP(kontr['ftp']['server'], encoding=kontr['ftp']['encoding'])`, спасибо. Мне казалось, что уже все функции просмотрел на наличие кодировки. И почему то решил, что её можно установить после соединения

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо @insolor в решении проблемы

Вкратце - кодировка устанавливается до авторизации. Чего я не заметил

На данном примере решение будет таким

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(kontr['ftp']['server'], encoding=kontr['ftp']['encoding'])
```